# Designing and managing a captive portal

Tags: wifi, captive-portal

I'd like to learn more about how a captive portal works, especially the management system regarding usage, security monitoring, billing, security architecture etc.

Does anybody know any good resources for this? I either find cheap sales-talk, or installation guides...

Answer (score 2):

There are [a large number of open source hotspot software suites available](http://sourceforge.net/directory/os%3alinux/?q=hotspot&sort=update). [EasyHotSpot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/easyhotspot/) has an integrated billing system.  I have not audited these applications and i have no idea how secure they are.

From a security perspective, "captive portals" break ssl pretty badly. [Convergence](http://convergence.io/),  which is the Anti-MITM addon for firefox will detect captive portals as being a MITM attack.  Which is true,  it is a MITM attack thats trying to get money from you.

There is a fundamental flaw in all of these "pay to use" wireless networks in that they are authenticating paying customers via a MAC address. Unfortunately with wireless networks,  the attacker can see every user's MAC address and just spoof their own.

Other security concerns are that non-paying customers should never be able to route packets to the open Internet.  Sometimes these networks will route DNS traffic,  and its possible to route [IP over DNS](http://thomer.com/howtos/nstx.html).  Or route IP over just about any other protocol (In fact I can't name a protocol above layer 1 that can't be used...).

A PHP remote file include vulnerability in your captive portal software could allow the attacker to gain access to the open Internet (as well as remote code execution on your box :-).  SQL Injection should also be a concern as it could an attacker to authenticate as a paying customer.